# Join table multiple columns groupBy with count in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to group joindraw table with count, but getting the following error. How can i get the count and group via multiple columns?

**Controller**

```
$joindraw_participants = Joindraw::where('product_id', $id)
                         ->groupBy('user_id', 'created_at')
                         ->with('user')->take(10)->desc()->get();
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'yangmao.joindraw.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `joindraw` where `product_id` = 1 group by `user_id` order by `joindraw`.`created_at` desc limit 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With strict mode enable groupBy needs all the columns in the select to be in groupBy also. To remove this validation either you can set `strict => false` in `config/database.php` for `mysql` or you can specify the modes so that other modes won't be affected. Like this:

```
'modes' => [
    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an empty array of **modes** to overwrite the default in your **config/database.php** file.

```
'mysql' => [
  'modes' => [],
],
```